# Sentry - Log Flask and Sentry at the same time / same DSN

Tags: python, logging, flask, celery, sentry

*Edit: Title and added some code samples.*

I'm trying to work out how to send both Celery worker and Flask logging to Sentry using the same DSN.

Setup is as follows:

- Flask app sends async tasks to a Celery worker.
- Flask and Celery worker are each running in linked Docker containers
- We're using the [Application Factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) pattern to create the app instances on the fly within the `__init__.py` file, so that's where the Celery and Sentry setup stuff currently happens:

(The code has been simplified for demo purposes.)

```
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=config[config_name].CELERY_BROKER_URL)
client = Client(dsn={my_dsn}, transport=HTTPTransport, )
sentry = Sentry(client=client)
def create_app(config_filename): 
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    # https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/flask/#extended-setup :
    sentry.init_app(app, logging=True, level=logging.INFO, )
    # https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/celery/ :
    register_logger_signal(client, loglevel=logging.INFO)
    register_signal(client)
    return app
```

By following the [Sentry Celery instructions](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/celery/), Sentry (in their own words) "hijack(s) Celery error handling", and works well. However, this then drops the Flask error handling in the process.

Is there a way to register both loggers (Flask and Celery) so that they both send log entries up to Sentry? Or should the Celery registration take place in the separate `celery_worker.py` file that runs within the Celery container?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], worker_send_task_events=True, task_send_sent_event=True)
celery.conf.update(app.config)

client = Client(dsn={my_dsn})
sentry = Sentry(app, dsn={my_dsn})
register_logger_signal(client)
register_logger_signal(client, loglevel=logging.INFO)
register_signal(client)
register_signal(client, ignore_expected=True)
```